# Panasonic G7 - Low cost zoom lens for video

Tags: camera, lenses

I'm about to buy the Panasonic Lumix G7 (body) and I would really like some advice about the best lens I can get for it at **less than 400$** if possible. I want it for shooting video, and the lens should be a zoom lens.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Joca Pinto :) For which area of application? Please add a bit more context in order to get a solid answer. Thanks.

Comment: @poor Already edited!

Answer (score 1):

A common zoom range of Panasonic MFT lenses is 14-42(45)mm. As an owner of such a lens I found out it's quite a compromise for city videos. 14mm is wide, but often times not wide enough for buildings. 42mm is tele, but not enough for detail shots.

Here are some with a more practical zoom range:

- Panasonic Lumix G Vario HD 14-140mm f/4.0-5.8 ASPH./MEGA O.I.S.
- Panasonic Lumix G Vario 14-140mm f/3.5-5.6 ASPH. POWER O.I.S.
- Panasonic LUMIX G VARIO 35-100mm f/4.0-5.6 ASPH. MEGA O.I.S.

I don't want to get more specific into prices, because they may change fast or be different in other countries.